# Forcing "+0000" timezone for RFC2822 times in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time, formatting, rfc822, rfc2822

How can I force the `Time.rfc2822` function to spit out `+0000`?

Ruby lets me parse [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) formatted times pretty easily:

```
require 'time'
time = Time.parse('14 Aug 2009 09:28:32 +0000')
puts time
=> "2009-08-14 05:28:32 -0400"
```

But what about displaying times?  Notice that the time it parsed is a local time.  No worries, I can convert it back to a UTC time with `gmtime`:

```
puts time.gmtime
=> "2009-08-14 09:28:32 UTC"
```

I can then put it back into RFC2822 format:

```
puts time.gmtime.rfc2822
=> "Fri, 14 Aug 2009 09:28:32 -0000"
```

Unfortunately, this is not quite what I want.  Notice that the **`+0000`** is now **`-0000`**.  According to RFC2822, this is because:

> The form "+0000" SHOULD be used to indicate a time zone at
>      Universal Time.  Though "-0000" also indicates Universal Time, it is
>      used to indicate that the time was generated on a system that may be
>      in a local time zone other than Universal Time and therefore
>      indicates that the date-time contains no information about the local
>      time zone.

Great - so how can I force `+0000` other than monkey-patching the `rfc2822` function?

Comment: If you set the time zone to universal time before calling gmtime.rfc2882 do you get the appropriate output?

It seems like it's reporting what it should be reporting, as I think Time.zone should be set to your local zone, by default.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  However, I did find that the DateTime class is much nicer; `DateTime.parse('14 Aug 2009 09:28:32 +0000').rfc2822` yields `"Fri, 14 Aug 2009 09:28:32 +0000"`.

Comment: Boy, that's strange... and yes: my thinking on the timezone thing got a bit muddied. Screwing around in the console to think up something for you helped straighten me out... didn't give me anything to share with you, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my monkeypatch solution:

```
class Time
  alias_method :old_rfc2822, :rfc2822
  def rfc2822
    t = old_rfc2822
    t.gsub!("-0000", "+0000") if utc?
    t
  end
end
```

If you have a non-monkeypatch solution, I would *love* to see it!

Answer (score 0):

simplest way if you don't need to use on multiple places

```
 Time.now.gmtime.rfc2822.sub(/(-)(0+)$/, '+\2')
 => "Fri, 31 Mar 2017 08:39:04 +0000"
```

or as a static (singleton) method version

```
require 'time'
module MyCustomTimeRFC
  def custom_rfc2822(time)
    time.gmtime.rfc2822.sub(/(-)(0+)$/, '+\2')
  end

  module_function :custom_rfc2822
end

t = Time.now
p MyCustomTimeRFC.custom_rfc2822(t)
#=> "Fri, 31 Mar 2017 08:43:15 +0000"
```

or as module extension if you like the oop style with ruby flexibility.

```
require 'time'
module MyCustomTimeRFC
  def custom_rfc2822
    gmtime.rfc2822.sub(/(-)(0+)$/, '+\2')
  end
end

t = Time.now
t.extend(MyCustomTimeRFC)
p t.custom_rfc2822
#=> "Fri, 31 Mar 2017 08:43:15 +0000"
```